Getting sql injection while scanning code with "Source Code Analysis Tools"
I have following java code (just an example)
StringBuilder sql = Select * from table_name;

if(order) {
    sql.append( "order by name")
} else {
    sql.append("order by age");
}

PreparedStatement st = cn.prepareStatement(sql.toString());

This code is failing quality check done by propriety "Source Code Analysis Tools". We are getting sql injection errors. I think probably this is due to append function I am using. Although we are not appending any dynamic parameter in the query. Is there any way I can modify the above code so that I do not get sql injection errors.

This code is not vulnerable to SQL injection currently (as the appended text is not user-provided), but if someone were to extend this code later on in a way that allowed uncontrolled text to get into that string, you would have a security issue. Your options are to accept that risk and suppress the warning (if the analysis tool supports that), write two separate, static strings for each query, or use a query builder.
